# people refiners on "everything page" sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, refiner, refinement-panel

Is there a way to get people refiners such as "SPS-department" , "SPS_Skills" etc in the refiners sections on the Everything results page provided by sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, "no", at least not without changing a bunch of the default search behavior. "Everything" does not include People (except for the query rule result blocks), so those managed properties from the User Profiles are not part of the result set.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the answer. any idea as to what all settings default behavior of search we have to change

Comment: There are a lot, you would start by changing the default Result Source, it excludes people. But there is a bunch of other stuff, like pushing People properties into the Content index rather than the PeopleIdx. It would be a huge task requiring a lot of testing.

Comment: Can we find this information anywhere?

Comment: I doubt anyone has ever tried. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: On everything page ... we are displaying users, documents, pages, sites etc... On the left hand panel we have refiners for each of the objects.. We are able to get the refiners for documents, pages but for people refiners such as Skills and Department yield no results, even though people data is on the page

Comment: How are you "displaying users"? Is that in a Result Block from a Query Rule or have you change the OOB result source? By default the People Index (and thus the managed properties) are not part of the content index, so what you are seeing is what I would expect.

Comment: I am doing it through the users in a Result block from a Query Rule. What would the query look like if we change the OOB result source?

Comment: OK, the result block does not contribute to the core results, so you won't get refinable properties. Those only come from the main result set.